# Password reset in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view at `/Account/ResetPassword` where the user will provide an email address for the account who's password they want to reset.

The email sent for the password reset will contain a link that looks something like this:
`/Account/ResetPassword/{reset key}`

I'm not sure how or where to design the view for the creation of the new password though.
It occurred to me to use a partial view that has its master set to the ResetPassword view, but having to name the view confuses me...

The url suggests a dynamic name, so how do I create the View?

Comment: What's different between the "new password" view and the "reset password" view?

Comment: "reset password" view just asks for the email address. If the submitted email address exists in the db, then the site will send the email. "new password" view will allow the user to set the new password - or inform the user that the reset token has expired

Comment: Why don't you use `/Account/ConfirmResetPassword/{reset key}` as the link in the email, then if the reset key is correct, redirect user to another view like `/Account/ChangePassword` where user can change the password?

Comment: @ekad I've got half of that set up as well, I'm just not sure how to do the redirect... `return View("ChangePassword", "Account");`?

Comment: You can use `return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", "Account")` after checking if the reset key is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with the inheritance of the `ResetPassword` view, you aren't gaining much given it's only a single field. I would create a distinct view for `CreatePassword`, you can determine which view you want to return based on whether the `reset key` parameter is provided or not e.g.

```
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string resetKey)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(resetKey)) {
        return View(); // will return "ResetPassword" view
    } else {
        // check validity of key then redirect if necessary
        return RedirectToAction("CreatePassword");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create `/Account/ConfirmResetPassword/{reset key}` as the link in the email. If the reset key is correct, then redirect user to another view, let's say `/Account/ChangePassword` where user can change the password. If the reset key is incorrect, then stay on `/Account/ConfirmResetPassword/{reset key}` and display a message that the reset key is invalid.

This would be the controller action method for `/Account/ConfirmResetPassword/{reset key}`

```
public ActionResult ConfirmResetPassword(string resetKey)
{
    bool isResetKeyCorrect = ...; // check if resetKey is correct here.

    if (isResetKeyCorrect)
    {
        // redirect to /Account/ChangePassword
        return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", "Account");
    }
    else
    {
        // Display a message saying that the reset key is invalid
        .......

        return View();
    }
}
```